# If else multiple tuples in a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, tuples

I am having an if method to check whether the [1] index value inside a tuple is less or equal to 255. While im feeding this method a single tuple inside a list it works eg [(0, 323)], but when im feeding the [(0, 323), (1, 1)] it doesn't.

```
if [i for i in a if i[1] <= 255]:
    print("a")
else:
    print("b")
```

Example if my values are [(0, 323)] it correctly prints b but when they change to a multiple tuple inside the same list [(0, 323), (1, 1)] it just prints a which is not correct. Any inputs please?

Comment: just use if a[1][1] <= 255:

Comment: what do you want to check - that all elements at index 1 are less than 255 or that at least one is less than 255?

Comment: That just in all indexes values wont get past 255 for that method to be true, eg print "a" if are less or equal to 255. @PavanKumarTS , already tried that and it gives me the 'int' object is not subscriptable error

Answer (score 2):

> Example if my values are [(0, 323)] it correctly prints b but when they change to a multiple tuple inside the same list [(0, 323), (1, 1)] it just prints a which is not correct. Any inputs please?

The behaviour is perfectly in line with the code:

```
[i for i in a if i[1] <= 255]
```

will return a list of all the tuples where the second item is under 255. For your second test case it returns `[(1, 1)]`.

This is then interpreted in a boolean context, in Python collections are generally "truthy" if the collection is non-empty and "falsy" is empty. A list of one element is non-empty, therefore truthy, therefore "a".

If you want this to pass when *all* tuples have a second value under 255, then that's a job for... [the `all` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

```
# transform the comprehension because `all([])` is `True` which seems
# undesirable here
if all(thing <= 255 for _, thing in a):
    print("a")
else:
    print("b")
```

Incidentally, `i` is colloquially an *index*, since this is not the case here `i` should be avoided. Same with `j`.

For a genering *e*lement prefer `e`, or better provide a name which actually explains what the thing is.

Comment: The all function saved the day, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking if there is ANY tuple in the list whose second item is less or equal to one. If that's what you want, `any()` would be better:

```
if any(each for each in a if each[1] <= 255):
    print("Yup, at least one tuple matched")
else:
    print("Nope, not a single one")
```

If you want to check if all the tuples matches, you use `all()`.

If you want to check each item, you need to loop over the list:

```
for each in a:
    if each[1] <= 255:
        print(f"{each} matches")
    else:
        print(f"{each} does not match")
```